# Rationality of a power series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-power-series

> Consider a power series $p = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i \in \mathbb{Q}[[z]]$, which corresponds to a rational function. (That means, that there exist $q,r \in \mathbb{Q}[z]$ such that $p$ is the unique solution to the equation $q \cdot x = r$ in $\mathbb{Q}[[z]]$.)
>   Now let's take a natural number $k \geq 2$ and define $\bar p := \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{k \cdot i} z^i$.
>   I wonder if $\bar p$ is a rational function, too.

I am grateful for every support. I already tried to apply some rationality-criterions I know, but have not been successful so far. Perhaps anyone knows a criterion which suits to this situation, or a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. $\bar{p}$ is rational: Let $\gamma=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{k})$ and set $w_j=z \gamma^j$, $1\leq j\leq k$. Then 
$$ \bar{p}(z^k)=\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} p(w_j) = \frac{1}{k} \frac{\sum_j r(w_j) \prod_{n\neq j} q(w_n)}{\prod_m q(w_m)}=\frac{R(w_1,\ldots,w_k)}{Q(w_1,\ldots,w_k)}$$
where $R$ and $Q$ are symmetric polynomials in the $k$ variables. Since the $w_j$'s are the solutions to  $w^k-1=0$ (so only the $0$'th and the $k$'th coefficients are non-zero) the only non-zero symmetric polynomials are those with powers that are multiples of $k$ and the coefficients will be rational as well. Therefore, (setting $Z=z^k$):
$$ \bar{p}(Z) = \frac{\tilde{R}(Z)}{\tilde{Q}(Z)}$$
for some $\tilde{Q},\tilde{R}\in {\Bbb Q}[Z]$

Comment: Thank you for effort, but there is still one argument which I don't understand: It's clear that the $\gamma ^i$ (where $1 \leq i \leq k$) are the solutions to $w^k-1=0$. But why does this imply that only terms like  $z^0, z^k, z^{2k}, ...$ occur finally?

Comment: Good question! You may see this from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial   Any symmetric polynomial may be expressed in terms of the power sum polynomials (see a bit toward the bottom af the wiki page). But only the powers that are multiple of $k$ will be non-zero and by my construction that corresponds precisely to the terms mentioned. Does that clarify?

Comment: Thanks, now everything is clear. To summarize it: For the proof it is crucial that the power sum symmetric polynomials generate the symmetric polynomials. And these power sum symmetric polynomials get along quite well with the roots of unity.

Comment: Yes, this is called 'pure magic' !